# How to use the result of previous observable chain?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactive

After some flatMap chain, I want use all previous result in the end, suppose I have the following code:

```
func getObservable1() -> Observable<API1Response> {

    ...
}

func getObservable2(param: API1Response) -> Observable<API2Response> {

    ...
}

func getObservable3(param: API2Response) -> Observable<API3Response> {

    ...
}

getObservable1()
    .flatMap { api1Response in
        return getObservable2(api1Response) 
    }
    .flatMap { api2Response in
        return getObservable3(api2Response) 
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { api3Response  in
        // I want to use both of api1Response and api2Response here
    })
```

How can I do that?

Should I save the api response to out scope variable and then use its latter?

Something like:

```
var api1Response: API1Response?
func getObservable1() -> Observable<API1Response> {
    ...

    self.api1Response = api1Response
    ...
}
...
getObservable1()
    ...
    .subscribe(onNext: { api3Response  in
        // use ap1Response here
        print(self.api1Response)
    })
```

Thanks!

-----UPDATE-----

Base on @Misternewb answer, I post runable code for test.

```
func getObservable1() -> Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.of(1)
}

func getObservable2(num: Int) -> Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.of(num + 1)
}

func getObservable3(num: Int) -> Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.of(num + 10)
}


getObservable1()
    .flatMap { ret1 in
        return getObservable2(num: ret1).map { (ret1, $0) }
    }
    .flatMap { ret1, ret2 in
        return getObservable3(num: ret2).map { (ret1, ret2, $0) }
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { ret1, ret2, ret3 in
        print(ret1)
        print(ret2)
        print(ret3)
    })
```

Output

```
1
2
12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
func getObservable1() -> Observable<API1Response> {
  return .empty()
}

func getObservable2(_ param: API1Response) -> Observable<API2Response> {
  return .empty()
}

func getObservable3(_ param: API2Response) -> Observable<API3Response> {
  return .empty()
}

func request() {
  getObservable1()
    .flatMap { api1Response in
      return getObservable2(api1Response).map { (api1Response, $0) }
    }
    .flatMap { api1Response, api2Response in
      return getObservable3(api2Response).map { (api1Response, api2Response, $0) }
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { api1Response, api2Response, api3Response  in

    })
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. I've added your runable code in my question. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this response to be in prerequisite order or you just need successful completion of all of them?

If you need to wait for completion of request #1 and request #2 then you can use

```
Observable.combineLatest(requestObservable1, requestObservable2)
  .flatMap { (requestResult1, requestResult2) -> Observable<You-Data-Type> in
     // Use result from request #1 & #2
     return requestObserver3
  }.subscribe(onNext: { (resultRequest3) in
  })
  ...
```

Comment: I want response to be in prerequisite order.
Observable2 uses Observable1's response as a parameter.
Actually, in the end, I want to use both of response1, response2, response3 at once.
But reponse2 depends on response1 and response3 depends on response2.
Thanks!